# How to get string text from AutoCompleteTextView using if else?

Tags: java, android

```
public class Cari extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher,View.OnClickListener {
TextView hasil, teks, teks2;
AutoCompleteTextView edit;
Button prev, terpilih;
String[] item = { "Matahari","Merkurius","Venus","Bumi","Mars","Yupiter","Saturnus","Uranus","Neptunus" };

    hasil = findViewById(R.id.hasil);
    edit = findViewById(R.id.edit);
    edit.addTextChangedListener(this);
    edit.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, item));

    teks = findViewById(R.id.title);
    Typeface customfont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/Starjout.ttf");
    teks.setTypeface(customfont);

    teks2 = findViewById(R.id.titleDes);
    Typeface customfont2 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "font/Starjout.ttf");
    teks2.setTypeface(customfont2);

    terpilih = findViewById(R.id.pilih);
    terpilih.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
    edit.getText();
}

public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
//not used
}

public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
//not used
}

public void onClick(View a) {
    switch (a.getId()) {
        case R.id.pilih:
            Toast.makeText(this, "Kamu memilih Planet "+edit.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mpilih();
            break;
    }
}

private void mpilih() {
    if (//what statement should add) {
      //here too *hasil.setText();
    }
    else {
      //here too
    }

}
```

How to make if else statement and set TextView hasil to get res/value/string name sun

this my first time programming using android studio, so i don't know too much about java mobile code. And sorry for bad English. Hope you understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getText()` to get `AutoCompleteTextView` value.
Here's the example of checking condition if `AutoCompleteTextView` is empty.

```
private void mpilih() {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(edit.getText())) {
            hasil.setText(getString(R.string.sun));
        } else {
            edit.setError("Please enter your selection");
        }
    }
```

If you're using only those fixed item as selection, i suggest you use Spinner instead..

**EDIT**

For multiple 'if' you can use it like this

```
    if (edit.getText().equals("Matahari")) {
        hasil.setText(getString(R.string.sun));
    } else if (edit.getText().equals("Bumi"){
        hasil.setText(getString(R.string.earth));
    }
```

Comment: that code doesn't work with multiple "if". The code only read one data

Comment: @JS4 multiple "if" example.

Comment: that code doesn't read hasil.setText(getString(R.string.sun)); it's directly to code : else {
            edit.setError("Please enter your selection");
        }